# Violación de segmento (core generado) con matriz dinámica

Tags: c++, linux-mint

Me encuentro realizando un  juego de damas, mi tablero debe ser creado de forma dinámica.

Tengo diferentes métodos, los cuales se encargan de reservar memoria, liberar memoria, llenar el tablero y mostrarlo. Pero, al momento de mostrarlo me da el siguiente error:

> error de segmentación ('core generado')

Adjunto el código:

```
//llenado del tablero.
void Tablero:: llenarTablero(){
  inicializarMatriz();
    for(int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<tamanio;j++){
        if(i % 2==0 && j % 2==0 && i<=2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Casilla();
        }
        if(i % 2==0 && j %2 !=0 && i<=2){
          tablero[i][j]=new Peon("1");
        }
        if(i %2 !=0 && j %2 ==0 && i<=2){
          tablero[i][j]=new Peon("1");
        }
        if(i %2 !=0 && j %2 !=0 && i<=2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Casilla();
        }
        if(i >2 && i< tamanio-2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Casilla();
        }
        if(i %2 ==0 && j %2 !=0 && i>= tamanio-2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Peon("2");
        }
        if(i %2 !=0 && j %2 ==0 && i>= tamanio-2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Peon("2");
        }
        if(i %2 !=0 && j %2 !=0 && i>= tamanio-2){
          tablero[i][j]= new Casilla();
        }
      }
    }
  }
//y acá es donde creo que me genera el error
void Tablero:: mostrarTablero(){
  //string dato;
  for(int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<tamanio;j++){
      cout<<tablero[i][j]->getColor();//hasta aca ejecuta 
    }
  }
}
```

Acá es donde hago el llamado, donde creo los objetos:

```
void FabricaIa:: creaModo(){
  JugadorPer* player1=new JugadorPer();
  player1->pedirNombre();
  JugadorIa* playerIa=new JugadorIa();
  Peon* peonPlayer1=new Peon();
  Peon* peonPlayer2=new Peon();
  peonPlayer1->pedirColor();
  cout<<peonPlayer1->imprimirColor();
  Tablero* tableroIa=new Tablero();
  tableroIa->pedirTamanio();
  tableroIa->inicializarMatriz();
  tableroIa->llenarTablero(/*peonPlayer1,peonPlayer2*/);
  tableroIa->mostrarTablero();
}
```

Según lo que he leído el error de segmentación es cuando intento acceder a memoria que no reservé.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a modificar un poco tu código para ver como estás generando tu `tablero`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void llenarTablero( char tablero[8][8] ) {
  const int tamanio = 8;

  for(int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<tamanio;j++){
      if( i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0 && i <= 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'C';
      if( i % 2 == 0 && j %2 != 0 && i <= 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'P';
      if( i %2 != 0 && j %2 == 0 && i <= 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'P';
      if( i %2 != 0 && j %2 != 0 && i <= 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'C';
      if( i > 2 && i < tamanio - 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'C';
      if( i %2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0 && i >= tamanio - 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'P';
      if( i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0 && i> = tamanio - 2) tablero[i][j] = 'P';
      if( i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0 && i>= tamanio - 2 ) tablero[i][j] = 'C';
    }
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  char tablero[8][8];

  memset( tablero, 'N', 8 * 8 );

  llenarTablero( tablero );

  for( int fil = 0; fil < 8; ++fil ) {
    printf( "%.8s\n", tablero[fil] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Si lo ejecutas, obtenemos lo siguiente:

> CPCPCPCP
>   PCPCPCPC
>   CPCPCPCP
>   CCCCCCCC
>   CCCCCCCC
>   CCCCCCCC
>   NPNPNPNP
>   PCPCPCPC

Pues ya lo tienes. Las letras `N` indican zonas de tu `tablero` **que están sin inicializar**. No muestras como realizas la reserva de memoria, así que, o contienen valores aleatorios, o bien contienen valores `nullptr`.

El resultado es el mismo en ambos casos: cuando llegas a

```
cout << tablero[i][j]->getColor( );
```

intentas acceder a una dirección incorrecta de memoria. El Sistema Operativo lo detecta, detiene tu programa, y te muestra el mensaje que ya conoces.

Deberías aprovechar tu función `inicializarMatriz( )` para rellenar todo el tablero, haciendo `new Casilla( )` en todas las posiciones. Con eso ya te ahorras los `if( )` que asignan `new Casilla( )`. Y modificar el resto de tus `if( )` de forma que si tienes que colocar una pieza en una casilla, realices el `delete` correspondiente:

```
void Tablero::llenarTablero( ) {
  inicializarMatriz( );

  for( int i = 0; i < tamanio; ++i ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < tamanio; ++j ) {
      if( i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0 && i <= 2 ) {
        delete tablero[i][j];
        tablero[i][j] = new Peon( "1" );
      }
      if( i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0 && i <= 2 ) {
        delete tablero[i][j];
        tablero[i][j] = new Peon( "1" );
      }
      if( i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0 && i >= tamanio - 2 ){
        delete tablero[i][j];
        tablero[i][j] = new Peon( "2" );
      }
      if( i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0 && i >= tamanio - 2 ) {
        delete tablero[i][j];
        tablero[i][j] = new Peon( "2" );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: En vez de crear y luego borrar quedaría un poco más bonito si primero pones los peones y luego recorres la tabla rellenando los huecos con casillas

Comment: @eferion Pues también. Fui a lo fácil.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya había solucionado lo del tablero,pero no había pensado lo de usar mejor a ilicializar